$\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} e^{-\max \left(|x|^3,|y|^3,|z|^3\right)} x^2 y^2 z^2 d x d y d z$
Problem: Calculate $I = \iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} e^{-\max \left(|x|^3,|y|^3,|z|^3\right)} x^2 y^2 z^2 d x d y d z$
Attempt: denote $ f(x,y,z) =  e^{-\max \left(|x|^3,|y|^3,|z|^3\right)} x^2 y^2 z^2 $, note that $ f $ is symmetric under permutations, hence $ I = \iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} f(x,y,z)  d x d y d z  = \iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} e^{-\max \left(|x|^3,|y|^3,|z|^3\right)} x^2 y^2 z^2 d x d y d z $   = $ 3! \iiint_{ |x| \leq |y| \leq |z|} e^{-|z|^3} x^2 y^2 z^2 d x d y d z $
We can take a Jordan measurable exhaustion $ E_n = [-n,n]^3 $ of $ \mathbb{R^3} $, define $ I_n = \iiint_{E^n} f(x,y,z)  d x d y d z = \iiint_{[-n,n]^3} e^{-\max \left(|x|^3,|y|^3,|z|^3\right)} x^2 y^2 z^2 d x d y d z $ , therefore
$ I_n =  3! \iiint_{ \substack{ |x| \leq |y| \leq |z| \\  , (x,y,z)\in [-n,n]^3}  } e^{-|z|^3} x^2 y^2 z^2 d x d y d z $
We'll calculate $ I_n $ and then $ I = \lim_{n\to \infty} I_n$
I don't know how to continue to simplify $ I_n $ to perform the calculation. I can see that the integrand is an even function for each variable so possibly some kind of variable substitution must be performed here to avoid the absolute values, I'm having difficulty as to how to continue, any ideas?
Thanks for the help!

Given the function $f(x,y,z) = e^{-\max \left(|x|^3,|y|^3,|z|^3\right)} x^2 y^2 z^2$ is symmetric under permutations of $x$, $y$, and $z$, and is even in each variable, we simplify the integral by focusing on the region $0 \leq x \leq y \leq z$ and considering only the positive octant, multiplying by 8 to account for all octants.
Simplification
By symmetry, we can write:
$I = 8 \cdot 3! \iiint_{0 \leq x \leq y \leq z} e^{-z^3} x^2 y^2 z^2 \,dx\,dy\,dz$
Integration Steps

Integrate with respect to $x$:
$\int_0^y x^2 \,dx = \frac{1}{3}y^3$

Integrate with respect to $y$:
$\int_0^z \frac{1}{3}y^5 \,dy = \frac{1}{18}z^6$

Integrate with respect to $z$:
$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{18}z^8 e^{-z^3} \,dz$


Substitution
Let $u = z^3$, thus $du = 3z^2\,dz$. The bounds change from $z = 0$ to $z = \infty$ become $u = 0$ to $u = \infty$. The integral becomes:
$\frac{1}{18} \int_0^{\infty} u^{8/3} e^{-u} \frac{du}{3}$
Integration and Final Calculation
The integral simplifies to:
$\frac{1}{54} \int_0^{\infty} u^{8/3} e^{-u} \,du$
Utilizing the Gamma function $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$ for the integral of $u^{n-1} e^{-u}$ from $0$ to $\infty$, we find:
$\frac{1}{54} \Gamma\left(\frac{11}{3}\right) = \frac{1}{54} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{5}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot 1 = \frac{10}{81}$
Multiplying by the factors for symmetry and the positive octant:
$I = 8 \cdot 6 \cdot \frac{10}{81} = \frac{16}{9}$
Therefore, the final result of the integral is:
$I = \frac{16}{9}$
